# How do I specify multiple shell scripts as initialization actions for Dataproc cluster creation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Google's documentation says that `--initialization-actions` takes a list of GCS URLs. If I specify one:

```
--initialization-actions 'gs://my-project/myscript.sh'
```

This works fine.

```
--initialization-actions 'gs://my-project/myscript.sh', 'gs://my-project/myscript2.sh'
```

Gives the following error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Google Cloud Storage object does not exist 'gs://my-project/myscript.sh gs://my-project/myscript2.sh'
```

Same without quotes, and with or without a space after the comma.

I tried encapsulating in square brackets:

```
--initialization-actions ['gs://my-project/myscript.sh', 'gs://my-project/myscript2.sh']
```

And the error this time is:

```
Executable '['gs://my-project/myscript.sh', 'gs://my-project/myscript2.sh']' URI must begin with 'gs://'
```

I can confirm one million percent that the paths I am using are valid, and that both objects are valid shell scripts. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, the format needs to be:

```
--initialization-actions 'gs://my-project/myscript.sh, gs://my-project/myscript2.sh'
```

ie both scripts in a single set of quotes, with comma separating.

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the space between the scripts:

```
--initialization-actions gs://my-project/myscript.sh,gs://my-project/myscript2.sh
```